# Resuming figure and table counters from other Rtex file

Tags: counters, multiple-files, setcounter

I am currently working on a project in overleaf which is currently divided into three documents:

- a main text document
- a supplementary Figures and Tables document
- a supplementary text document.

The supplementary Figures and Tables document contains images that are referenced to in the main text via the xr package (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf), while the supplementary text contains some more explanations, and other figures that go along with these.

Now, my problem is that I would like the figure names in the 2 supplementary documents to not clash, and so I would like the counters to figures and tables in the supplementary text to start from the last label used in the supplementary figures document.
(ie, if the last figure in Supp Fig is S30, I want the first figure in SuppText to be S31).

For the moment, I have been able to 'partially' solve this problem by manually setting in the preamble:

```
\setcounter{figure}{30}
\setcounter{table}{5}.
```

However, I would like to know whether there is a way to automate this, so that I do not have to go and look for how many figures the Supplementary documents have everytime I make a change.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first file is something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\newwrite\savefile
\immediate\openout\savefile=savefile1.tex
\AtEndDocument{\clearpage
\immediate\write\savefile{%
\string\setcounter{figure}{\the\value{figure}}^^J%
\string\setcounter{table}{\the\value{table}}^^J%
}}

\begin{document}

document one

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
FFF
\caption{Zzzz}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
FFF
\caption{Zzzz}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
TTT
\caption{Zzzz}
\end{table}


\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
FFF
\caption{Zzzz}
\end{figure}


\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
TTT
\caption{Zzzz}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Then after running it through latex, `savefile1.tex` will be

```
\setcounter{figure}{3}
\setcounter{table}{2}
```

so your second file can be of the form

```
\documentclass{article}


\input{savefile1}
\begin{document}


document two

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
FFF
\caption{Zzzz}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Producing

[image]

Obviously you can chain as many of these save/restores together as you need.